# Use newer NiFi processors in older versions

Tags: apache-nifi

Is there a way to use processors (e.g. `RetryFlowFile`) and services (e.g. `DatabaseRecordLookupService`) from NiFi 1.10 in older versions (specifically in 1.8)? Are they backwards-compatible?

Comment: The NiFi API is very robust and we attempt to avoid breaking changes in minor version releases, so _in general_, a NAR from 1.10 will work in 1.8, but there can be exceptions. Check the [Release Notes](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Release+Notes) for call outs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backwards-compatibility is not guaranteed.
What you can do : Retrieve the RetryFlowFile nar from Nifi 1.10 and install it in your nar directory of your Nifi then restart your Nifi.
In your processor tab you should see 2 retryFlowFile procesor but with different version.

Comment: Using the NAR file from 1.10 did work. Unfortunately, you can't simply copy only one processor, but a whole package (`nifi-standard-nar-1.10.0.nar` in the case of `RetryFlowFile`).